# Cannot install sharp with Docker on M1 Mac

Tags: node.js, docker, macos-big-sur, apple-m1, sharp

Installing `sharp` on M1 Mac with `yarn install` is OK, but with Docker results in the following error:

```
error /usr/src/app/node_modules/sharp: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node install/can-compile && node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
Arguments: 
Directory: /usr/src/app/node_modules/sharp
Output:
sharp: Installation error: Use with glibc 2.24 requires manual installation of libvips >= 8.11.3
sharp: Please see https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install for required dependencies
```

I ensured that sharp version is `0.29.0`, as well as installed lipvips globally on the Mac with `brew install vips` however Docker still cannot build the app.

I followed the issue on GitHub https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/2460 but it didn't really help.

How could I force Docker to use that locally build lipvips? Or do you have any other suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In dockerfile instead of `Run npm install`, add following line

```
RUN SHARP_IGNORE_GLOBAL_LIBVIPS=1 npm install --arch=x64 --platform=linux sharp
```

Answer (score -1):

Try setting `export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64`

Comment: didn't really help, unfortunately. Still the same error